# Angular testing with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, tdd

I'm trying to create some test with Jasmine to test a web app.

how do you test content insert from the page?
I created an example included:
If i test the controller alone,with mocked data, the sum function provided in the example does work, but testing with the page, it causes an error because the numbers are converted to string, so, what is the correct approach to this kind of tests?

Here is an example i created to understand the problem i'm facing:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('provaController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.firstNumber = 0;
  $scope.secondNumber= 0;
  $scope.result = 0;


  $scope.sum = function() {
    $scope.result =   $scope.firstNumber + $scope.secondNumber;
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="provaController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstNumber" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="secondNumber" />

            <input type="button" ng-click="sum()" value="SUM"/>
    <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="result" />
        
        <p>First: -{{firstNumber}}- </p>
        <p>Sec: -{{secondNumber}}- </p>
        <p>Res: -{{result}}- </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The pen example is here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKYOxw

Answer (score 1):

the `input`s are setting your model values to the string representation of the numbers, instead of the numbers themselves.

if you set the `type` attribute of your inputs to `number` instead of `text` you get the result that you expect.

I've [updated your codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKYbxx) with the change

Comment: Thank you, but while this is true to achieve the expected result from the example code, the question is not about the example itself, but about understanding how to make a test to catch this kind of error, not just to correct the code

Comment: Can't test that with jasmine, you'd have to use [protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) to test html interaction.